# How to automatically indent source code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, indentation

How can I automatically indent source code in Visual Studio 2010?

I have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, but it does not work; is there any other way/plugin to do this?

Comment: What type of source code? If it doesn't work it's either corrupted VS install, or nonstandard file. Or different keyboard shortcut defaults, try the edit menu.

Comment: @Madman: I am using ViEmu, VAssitX. Its a C# source file. Now surprisely It works fine.

Comment: you just need to select all the text/code before doing CTRL+K, CTRL+F, then it should work

Comment: Code in VB.NET :-) ... On a serious note it still amazes me that certain features like this are not coalesced into both languages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you auto format code in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755942/how-do-you-auto-format-code-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> - Format whole doc
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> - Format selection

Also available in the menu via *Edit|Advanced*.

Thomas

Edit- 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - Format whole doc in VS 2010

Comment: I have tried both ways, and from the Edit|Advanced menu, and they are not doing anything to my source code. Other options like line indent are working. What could be wrong?

Comment: Chucky, have you considered removing Visual Studio and doing a clean install? I have a few times made so many changes that I've ruined it.

Comment: lol MS, "Advanced", because only "Advanced" users would want to format their code???

Comment: Side note: shortcut depends on your keyboard layout, so if one does not work - check what  Edit->Advanced says. Indeed you can customize it to you liking in Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard.

Answer (score 47):

In 2010 it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio 2010

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>k</kbd> +<kbd>d</kbd> indent the complete page.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>k</kbd> +<kbd>f</kbd> indent the selected Code.

For more help visit : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

every thing is there.

Answer (score 7):

In 2010 it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>k</kbd> +<kbd>d</kbd> for indentation

Answer (score 1):

Also, there's the handy little "increase indent" and "decrease indent" buttons. If you highlight a block of code and click those buttons the entire block will indent.

Comment: Set `Options > C/C++ > Formatting > Automatic Indentation on Tab` to `True` and press `TAB`.

Comment: I was attempting to compare an XML file to the checked in version in VS 2010, but the indent had changed, making it impossible to see real changes.  Using the format feature did not work, but 'increase indent' did.

Answer (score 0):

> > I have tried both ways, and from the Edit|Advanced menu, and they are not doing anything to my source code. Other options like line indent are working. What could be wrong? –  Chucky Jul 12 '13 at 11:06

Sometimes if it doesnt work, try to select a couple lines above and below or the whole block of code (whole function, whole cycle, whole switch, etc.), so that it knows how to indent.

Like for example if you copy/paste something into a case statement of a switch and it has wrong indentation, you need to select the text + the line with the case statement above to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that auto-indent does not work if there are syntax errors in the document. Get rid of the red squigglies, and THEN try CTRL+K, CTRL+D, whatever...