# How do you auto format code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, indentation

I know Visual Studio can auto format to make my methods and loops indented properly, but I cannot find the setting.

Comment: From top menu:   Edit --> Advanced --> Format Document

Comment: what about for 2019?

Comment: still the same in vs2019

Comment: Do you mean "how do you format a block of code with a couple keystrokes"?  That seems to be what the popular answers refer to (rather than "how do you auto format" ... as you type/paste/etc).

Comment: For Visual Studio 2017 . Using shortcut Ctrl + Alt + Enter

Comment: This feature will be available in Visual Studio 2022 17.1 - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70740018/11473934

Comment: You can use `ideal` formatting if you choose Tools -> Text Editor -> Advanced -> Text formatting method -> Ideal. It's much better than default formatting. Then just use ctrl + k and ctrl + d

Comment: I want to add an icon that does this to the toolbar, know where i can find it?

Comment: @zipzit - Edit / Advanced / Format document does absolutely nothing. How do you expect it to help here?

Answer (score 1773, accepted):

To format a selection: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

To format a document: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

See the [pre-defined keyboard shortcuts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/da5kh0wa(v=vs.100)). (These two are `Edit.FormatSelection` and `Edit.FormatDocument`.)

#### Note for macOS

On macOS, use the <kbd>CMD ⌘</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

- To format a selection: <kbd>CMD ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CMD ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- To format a document:
  <kbd>CMD ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CMD ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: vs 2010 seems to be ctrl + k, ctrl + d

Comment: Its Ctr + K, Ctrl + D in Visual Studio 2013 to format a document.

Comment: In VS2010, if you have `Format document is not available...` error message, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8812741/1016891

Comment: These are accurate for VS2013

Comment: VS2012 uses Ctrl-E,F and Ctrl-E,D

Comment: For the sake of posterity, you might consider updating this answer with the default keybindings for older versions of VS. I recognize the comments have the answers, but that's hardly a long-term solution.

Comment: Difference between `Ctrl+K` and `Ctrl+E`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942113/format-code-shortcut-for-visual-studio

Comment: Note: it didn't work until I fixed my compilation error

Comment: To format all code Visual Stupid 2010, use: Ctrl+A, Ctrl K, Ctrl F.

Comment: I dont know why Microsoft keeps changing these. For future reference, it can be found under Edit - > Advanced -> Format Document

Who knows, they're probably going to rename that menu in the next iteration.

Comment: Using VS 2017, Found it under Edit>Advanced>Format Document, but it doesn't form the .cshtml file.

Comment: Now-a-days it is `Shift + Alt + F` in windows, or you can find it in Command Palette ( `Ctrl + Shift + P' ) and type **Format Document**

Comment: On MacOS it is `Shift + Alt/options + F`

Comment: its ⇧⌥F for Mac, not what you said

Comment: If you using Visual Studio 2022 17.1 - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70740018/11473934

Comment: In the menu Edit, there is no option "Advanced". ctrl+k, ctrl+d has no effect. ctrl+k, ctrl+f says "is not a command".

Answer (score 202):

For Visual Studio 2010/2013/2015/2017/2019

- **Format Document (<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>)**, i.e. press&hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, press&release <kbd>K</kbd> then tap <kbd>D</kbd> as it is a sequence
- **Format Selection  (<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>)**

Toolbar **Edit -> Advanced** (If you can't see *Advanced*, select a code file in solution explorer and try again)

Your shortcuts might display differently to mine as I am set up for C# coding but navigating via the toolbar will get you to your ones.

If it isn't working, look for errors in your code, like missing brackets which stop auto format from working

Comment: If you find that it isn't working, check your brackets {}, (), when it doesn't work for me, it is because there are open brackets somewhere in the file.

Comment: Is there any way to not use a sequence of keys but just on combination of keys?

Comment: @UpulieHan I think you can edit your shortcuts Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Search for "Edit.FormatDocument" ... Ctrl+Alt+; seems like an available combo for me :)

Comment: If you are trying to auto format HTML code then this command won't work, instead look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329393/how-to-format-html-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 66):

I have installed an extension named "Format document on Save" which formats the whole document every time you save it.

For installing it in Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2017, on Tools just click the "Extensions and Updates...":

[image]

And then just go to "Online" at the left panel and search for "Format document on save":

[image]

Comment: Also you can install it by visual studio market place https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave

Comment: I tried it, but it looks like [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29482) is getting in the way. And I don't want to clean up what VS messed up while doing a cleanup.

Answer (score 50):

**Visual Studio 2019 & 2022**

1. **Format Document**, While you're **holding down** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button, first press <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>D</kbd>
2. **Format Selection**, While you're **holding down** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button, first press <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>F</kbd>

or just click **Edit** => **Advanced** => **Format Document** / **Format Selection**

[image]

Comment: Why do people keep mentioning that. It clearly does nothing. Oh right, the only thing it can actually do is indent code forward. It can't reformat code backward. So if there are spaces or tabs, it can't remove them, making it almost useless except in the single case where you have typed it in anyway. I can demonstrate horrible formatting that it can't do a single thing with - and yet, is obviously re-formattable.

Answer (score 45):

1. Go to menu *Tools* → *Extensions & Updates* and type "productivity" in search:

   [image: 1]
2. Install 'Productivity Power Tools 2015'
3. Restart Visual Studio.
4. Go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Productivity Power Tools* → *Power Commands* and check "Format document on save":

   [image: 2]

**Note:** In VS2022 we don't have power commands.

- If anyone want to have "Format document on save" and "Remove and sort using on save" install *Mads Kristensen* extension for VS2022 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CodeCleanupOnSave
- After installing this extension it will automatically "Format document on save", "Remove and sort using on save" and "Apply file header preferences".
- If we want to customize default settings click on "Configure Code Cleanup" menu item to add/remove any available fixers.
  [image]

Comment: Would have been good if it working while typing, as with VB.NET:

Comment: have to get used to formatting every new document you edit and committing changes before you actually change the file otherwise the commits can look pretty noisy

Comment: Installed the extension for visual studio 2019, i don'tsee powerCommands after HTML Copy.

Comment: It works for me, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.2

Answer (score 41):

Follow the steps below:

- Go to menu *Tools*
- Go to *Options*
- Go to the *Text Editor options*
- Click the language of your choice. I used *C#* as an example.

See the below image:

[image]

Comment: And once I've done this? I can't see any of those settings handle automatic indentation?

Comment: @MrJalapeno I have absolutely no idea what question I was answering here 6 years ago but 34 people have found it useful. Sorry for the confusion.

I probably misinterpreted the question in which case my answer applies since there are formatting related options in my answer. In hindsight, it's safe to say the OP was looking for ctrl+k, ctrl+d.

Answer (score 37):

Since`Visual Studio 2022 17.1` there is a builtin Feature to run code formatting on save (see [devblogs.microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/bringing-code-cleanup-on-save-to-visual-studio-2022-17-1-preview-2/)), meaning there is no need to install extensions like `Format document on Save`.

[image]

Be aware that there is a failure regarding the merge view when using the autoformat option - [github code cleanup - merge bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/60818).

Answer (score 29):

You can define new key bindings by going to *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *keyboard*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For me Ctrl E + D in VS2005 scheme :)

Answer (score 23):

On mac : <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

On ubuntu : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: This, unlike basically everything else here, still worked for me in 2021 (Ubuntu).

Comment: I'm glad to help =)

Answer (score 14):

In Visual Studio 2017, 2019, 2022

> Format Document is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>.

But...if you want to **add the Format Document button to a tool bar** do this:

- Right click on tool bar.
- Select "Customize.."
- Select the "Commands" Tab.
- Select the "Toolbar" radio button.
- Select "Text Editor" from the pull down next to the radio button (or whatever tool bar you want the button on)

Now...

- Click the <kbd>Add Command</kbd> button.
- Categories: Edit
- Commands: Document Format
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Answer (score 12):

I used to use these combinations. I automated this process on Save of a document. You can try my extension *[Format Document on Save](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ea1c920-69c4-441f-9979-ccc2752dac56)*.

Comment: Thanks for doing something that should just have been a checkbox in VS settings!

Answer (score 11):

If you display the *HTML Source Editing* toolbar, there is a "Format the Whole Document" button as well.

Comment: That's a really strange place for it.  I have been searching all over for this.

Comment: I have VS13, that toolbar does not have a "Format Document" button available.

Comment: Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL there is a "Format the whole document" button on the toolbar mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice if we could add it to other toolbars by **add or remove buttons>>customize**

Answer (score 10):

The solution provided in accepted answer does not apply to [Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012).

In case of Visual Studio 2012, the shortcuts are:

- For a highlighted block of code:
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- For the document-wide formatting:
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Actually it's not wrong. Both CTRL + K,F and CTRL + E,F do the exact same thing. If you go to EDIT -> Advanced, you will actually see the shortcuts listed as CTRL + E,D and CTRL + E,F. Also commenting can be done with either CTRL + K,C or CTRL + E,C. - Using VS2012 Premium with all the latest updates installed.

Comment: @Alan006 Interesting.  My installation of VS2012 Pro says Ctrl+ e,f/Ctrl + e,d are not commands.

Comment: I think it might be to do with what environment/development settings you choose initially on first launch. They both work for me though, so I wont complain :D

Comment: @Alan006 is right, the default environment for VS2010 and up uses the keyboard layout for "Visual Basic" (check **Tools -> Options -> Keyboard**). "Visual C# 2005" has slightly different keyboard bindings.

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio 2019 , "Code Cleanup" (RunDefaultCodeCleanup) is more advanced (taken from [ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate)):
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

[Options dialog box: *Text Editor* → *C#* → *Code Style* → *Formatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-formatting?view=vs-2019)

#### Auto formatting settings in Visual Studio

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Select the text you want to automatically indent.**

Click menu *Edit* → *Advanced* → *Format Selection, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Format Selection applies the smart indenting rules for the language in which you are programming to the selected text.

Step (1): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Step (2): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Step (3): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

Under menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Text Editor*, then going to the *Formatting* → *General* section of whatever language you wish to format you will find **General**. Check all three formatting check-boxes.

Under menu*Tools* → *Options* → *Text Editor*, then going to the **TABS** section of whatever language you wish to format you will find **Indenting**.  Select **Smart** and it will activate automatic formatting whenever you use one of the closing elements ; ) } within that block.

There isn't any need for keystrokes.

Comment: This doesn't improve "already messed up" code while VB.NET does this.

Answer (score 6):

In newer versions, the shortcut for the document-wide formatting is: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

You can add the buttons to your toolbar by clicking the little drop down arrow to the right of the last toolbar button, select "Add or Remove Buttons" and then click the buttons you want to add a tick to them. The button(s) you select will appear on your toolbar ...

[image]

Then you just select text and click the Increase Indent or Decrease Indent buttons. I tested this on Visual Studio 2013 only.

Answer (score 5):

Right click:

[image]

It works in Visual Studio 2015, maybe earlier version.

Answer (score 5):

The original question said "I cannot find the setting."

Simple answer is:  Look at top menu, then

> Edit --> Advanced --> Format Document

You will also see the currently assigned key strokes for that function.  Nothing special to memorize.  This really helps if you use multiple developer environments on different operating systems.

Answer (score 4):

Select the data and the right click and you will find this option.
*Format Document* and *Format Selection*:

[image: See this image]

Comment: This thread is about Visual Studio. Your comment talks about Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 2):

Just to further [Starwfanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756074/4841869) and [Ewan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31004374/4841869)'s answers, you can customise your IDE to add **any** button to **any** toolbar - so you can add the <kbd>Format</kbd> button (as the HTML Source Editing toolbar has) to any other toolbar (like Text Editing with all the other edit controls like increase/decrease indent).

Click the arrow to the right of the toolbar → *Add or Remove Buttons* → *Customize...* → Commands tab →  button.

**Document Format** and **Selection Format** are both under the **Edit** group.

(Tested in Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013)

Answer (score 1):

With the [Continuous Formatting](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/08afc8d1-4b74-44df-b012-f225ee9e9220) extension (commercial, developed by me), the code is formatted really automatically as you type.

Comment: That's great and should be included in VS by default, but the price is too high. For 19 € I would have said "Great!".

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 for C# code.

1. Scroll to the end of the file
2. Remove the last "curly bracket", }
3. Wait until the line above it shows an error
4. Replace the "curly bracket", }
   Fini. :)

Comment: Rewrite last `}`. That's it. lol

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Extension - [CodeMaid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid) is pretty fine.

Comment: Extension not found

Comment: With this extension, you can even right click a folder and cleanup all code in all files in it, very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If it's still not working then you can select your entire document, copy and paste and it will reformat.

So ...

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

This is the only thing that I have found that works in Visual Studio Community Edition on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Windows.

But you can always double check by doing following.

1. Go to menu *View* → *Command Palette* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for **Format Document**
3. You can press that to *Auto Format Code* or its hot key, written in front of it.

Comment: Command pallet doesn't exist in Visual Studio. You must be mistaking this with vscode.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it (or if you're eligible for the 30-day free trial) [JetBrains' ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can reformat a whole project directory.

Just install → right-click a directory → select *Cleanup Code* from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the right click menu (context menu) option to format the selection of the coding document. Take a look at the below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CodeMaid Extension.

You can get the extension from Visual Studio Market Place.
Here is the link to the extension. [CodeMaid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59460717/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, use the following:

Keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>

or

Menu *Edit* → *Advanced* → *Format Document*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JetBrains ReSharper, the easiest way to format your code is to use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> shortcut (*Reformat code*).

Answer (score 0):

Using VS 2017 I wanted to format web page HTML which somehow had become entirely left aligned.
Even after installing Productivity Power Tools this wouldn't work.

To fix, for HTML I had to go to
Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> HTML (Web Forms) and change;
Tabs Indenting = Smart and Tab = Keep Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2022, I am using search bar on top menu (Feature Search) and typing

> fix format

then press Enter.

-> Of course keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D is easier but often I forgot it!

Answer (score -1):

Cut/Paste of a section is another quick way (and easy to remember).

Comment: ...? that does not format anything for me. in fact, the reason I looked this up was to format AFTER cutting and pasting..

Comment: That does not format your code with the defatult settings. Maybe you have some setting / plugin that does the job after pasting. Up to Novermber 2018 (v 1.30.2) the way is SHIFT + ALT + F

Answer (score -1):

Simply hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

1. Windows <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. MacOS <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
3. Linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: vscode != visual studio

Answer (score -2):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    char filename[15];

    printf("Enter file name:");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    Automat(filename);
    freq(filename);
}

int Automat(char filename[]){

    FILE*fp;
    char c;
    int state = 1;
    int duma = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error");
        system("pause");
    }
    while (!feof(fp)){
        c = fgetc(fp);

        switch (state){
        case 1:
            if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == ' '){
                state = 3;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            if (c >='A'|| c<='Z'){
                break;
            }

        case 3: duma++;
            state = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Broq e : %d\n", duma);
    return 1;
}
int freq(char filename[]){

    FILE*fp;
    char c;
    int state = 1, sequence = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error");
        system("pause");
    }



    while (!feof(fp)){
        c = fgetc(fp);
        switch (state){
        case 1:
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
                state = 2;
                break;
            }

        case 2:
            if (c == '\t' || c == '\n'||c == ' '){
                sequence++;
                state = 1;
                break;

            }
        }

    }
    printf("Sequence is : %d\n", sequence);
}
```

Comment: The question was *"How do you auto format code in Visual Studio?"*. How does this answer address that?

Answer (score -5):

You can press shift + alt + F.

Comment: That's for VSCode.