# Visual studio Reformat Code/Document

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I can't find the Reformat button, I know I can use ctrl+k+d, but I wish to have also the toolbar with the button. can someone help me ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755942/how-do-you-auto-format-code-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use Edit > Advanced > Format Document and you can also move this as a button to any toolbar. Go to Tools > Customize > Commands, select Toolbar and push Add Command button. Then select Edit category and find Document Format.

Comment: thanks, I've searched the for the command in order to add it but didn't find it in the Edit category

Comment: Sorry it is called Document Format not Format Document in commands.

Comment: Mine does not show either "Format Document" nor "Document Format" under the edit menu list when adding a new command.  Any other thoughts on where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently VS2010 (maybe others) hide certain commands depending on the style you choose.  I chose Web Dev (code) as my choice and the Document Format is not present to be added to a toolbar.  But, if I change to C# Code (tools>Import/Export) then the Document Format command is right there in the Edit menu where others here have said it is.

I had to import the C# Dev layout, but unchecked colors and code formatting options (so it won't overwrite those).  What section you must import to get the format document button, I don't know, I didn't experiment that deep.

Seems stupid MS chose to force us down specific paths for layout with no convenient way to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find it in the Edit menu: you can also find it if you press CTRL + P and then type >format. The shortcut is SHIFT + ALT + F

[image]