# How does one paste and indent in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: sublimetext2, visual-studio-code

In Sublime text `cmd+shift+v` will paste and indent the code. Can this be done in visual studio code?

**Workaround**

I've made an extension that will let you paste and format with `cmd/ctrl+shift+v`.
Search for `pasteandformat`

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spoeken.pasteandformat

Comment: If I properly understand you need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755942/how-do-you-auto-format-code-in-visual-studio)

Comment: If you're feeling ambitious, you could start learning about developing [vscode extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview).  I am just starting to get into this, so I can't give you a complete roadmap.

Comment: The [`go` language extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go) would be a good reference.  In particular, the [formatting lib](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/blob/master/src/goFormat.ts) might show you how you might implement the formatting functionality for the desired language, and then you would need to figure out how to trigger that by attaching to the paste event (if that's possible).  But by the time you learn/implement that it might be out-of-the-box functionality in your desired language.

Comment: @EricLease I'm a fast learner ;) https://github.com/spoeken/pasteandformat
Took use of some buildt in commands instead of writing a formatter from bottom up.

Comment: @Spoeken great extension! I didn't want paste and format but only indent after paste, so I have coded an extension if you wanna try it https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rubymaniac.vscode-paste-and-indent most of the time it works..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since version 1.9.0, `editor.formatOnPaste` landed in VSCode.

Open **settings.json** via **Code -> Preferences - Settings** and search for `formatOnPaste`

> // Controls if the editor should automatically format the pasted
>   content. A formatter must be available and the formatter should be
>   able to format a range in a document.

```
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
```

Modify `false` to `true` since the default value is `false`

Source: [Changelog update 1.9.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_format-on-paste)

Answer (score 26):

Currently, Visual Studio Code doesn't provide this specific functionality.
We could vote for this feature at [Visual Studio's UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015) website.

There's already a ticket open for this feature: [Paste and auto align code](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/8626678-paste-and-auto-align-code). If you've got an account, you can vote for this feature so it gets more attention. If it has enough attention, Visual Studio Code's developers could take notice of this and maybe develop it.

**Current workaround**

After pasting the code,
You could use **CTRL+E, CTRL+D** for windows or **ALT+SHIFT+F** for mac.

But note that this will reformat the whole document, indenting according to the available rules for the source type.

If you only want this to be applied to the pasted code, select the code after pasting and then use **CTRL+E, CTRL+D** for windows or **ALT+SHIFT+F** for mac. Now the indenting/formatting is only applied to the pasted lines.

Comment: What (I'm) we are looking for is this functionality, but directly applied to the 'copied' text, without affecting the rest of the document.

Comment: I'm currently unaware of functionality in VS which provides the behaviour only on the pasted part.

Comment: I suggested an edit on your answer, that this feature currently isn't available and how users could vote for this feature in Visual Studio's UserVoice website: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/8626678-paste-and-auto-align-code. I also improved your 'fix' a little bit. If this edit gets approved, I'll be happy to grant you the well-deserved bounty.

Comment: You improved the answer quite a lot. So i thank you kind sir.

Comment: I just added an explanation of how to edit your key bindings file. But I could not find a way to add two commands for one shortcut. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: @mhx I've made an extension that will let you paste and format with `cmd/ctrl+shift+v`. Search for `pasteandformat` Note that it will format the whole document, not just what you pasted in.

Comment: @mhx Updated it. So now it only formats the pasted text :) If you find any issues you can report it at https://github.com/spoeken/pasteandformat

Comment: @spoeken awesome! Nice update... definitely will be using this for now. :-)

Comment: Looks like it's being implemented. See this UserVoice item: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752552-auto-indent-code-format

Comment: @martypdx yes there is, maybe it only says option on yours.