# Automatically adding spaces before semicolon in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have been using VS2015 for about a year but I have had to reinstall it recently and I can't find the option to automatically add spaces to a expression as soon as a semicolon is entered. I have use it before but just can't find it now.

**Example:**

*before semicolon:* `A=a+b+myFunction(a,b)`

*after semicolon:* `A = a + b + myFunction(a, b);`

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755942/how-do-you-auto-format-code-in-visual-studio) may help.

Comment: The body of your question seems very different from your title. The title suggests you want to add a space at the end of the expression, before the semicolon, whereas the body of your question suggests you want typing a semicolon to trigger automatic formatting.

Comment: Not exactly but its also very interesting @jaggedSpire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under *TOOLS*->*Options*->*C/C++*->*Formatting*, you'll want to have "**Automatically format statement when I type a ;**" checked.

[image]

Comment: There is a C++14 tag in the question, but I can confirm the option is there under C/C++ too

Comment: @KABoissonneault Thanks. Missed the tag. Updated for C/C++.

Comment: @Ionian316 I tried it but its not working even if clicking the *Automatically format statement when I type a ;*. Is it possible that another option overrides it?

Comment: @Jacko Check your settings under _C/C++->Formatting->Spacing_. Make sure none of them are set incorrectly, especially in the **Spacing for operators** section. Also, do you have any third-party plugins or tools installed?

Comment: I reset the settings, close and open Visual Studio 2015 and applied @Ionian316 answer and it worked! Thanks for your help and time.