# How to format HTML in a PHP file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I tried:

- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Also when I search for format via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, there are no search results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Visual Studio Code won't format HTML if the file has a PHP extension (index.php). I'm going to post a new question that includes this information.

Comment: In the bottom right of the screen, it will show PHP, if you click this, and select HTML, you can then format your text. Once formatted, switch back to PHP.

Answer (score 61):

On Windows, code formatting is available in VSCode through the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

On Mac, it is available through the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

On Ubuntu, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

Note: in the bottom right of the screen, it will show the text file form. Maybe plain text, PHP, HTML etc. If you click this you can switch the format of the file before issuing the above shortcuts.

Comment: This dont work...