# How do you auto format code in Visual Studio on save?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

is there any way to auto-format HTML and Javascript code on saving in Visual Studio like Visual Studio Code?

Comment: **See Also**: [How do you auto format code in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5755942/1366033)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since `Visual Studio 2022 17.1` there is a builtin Feature to run code formatting on save (see [devblogs.microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/bringing-code-cleanup-on-save-to-visual-studio-2022-17-1-preview-2/)), meaning there is no need to install extensions like `Format document on Save`.

[image]

Be aware that there is a failure regarding the merge view when using the autoformat option - [github code cleanup - merge bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/60818).

Comment: In 2022 this was finally built in!

Comment: Well it does not format xml documents like indenting in csproj files.

Comment: @NithinB it does if you change the settings for it in your `.editorconfig`. For instance, if I copy/paste inside `csproj` or `fsproj` files, it will format according to the rules set there.

Answer (score 8):

The plugin [Format document on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave) seems to to do what you ask:

> Enables auto formatting of the code when you save a file. Visual Studio supports auto formatting of the code with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> , <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> , <kbd>F</kbd> key shortcuts but with this extension the command `Format Document` is executed on Save.

Comment: The short cut is Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D according to the Shortcut settings for document formatting and Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F for selected text.