# What is the shortcut to format code in Visual Studio like NetBeans or Eclipse?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, format

I have some codes in my project. But looks disordered and i want to order it and indent it with a shortcut like ALT + SHIFT + F in Netbeans.

Can any one help me to do that.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: [How to automatically indent source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958903/how-to-automatically-indent-source-code)

Essentially:

> Ctrl+E, D - Format whole doc
>   Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F - Format selection

(from included link)

Comment: You really should have proposed duplicate instead of cloning the answer...  Or at least provide some additional info...

Comment: Thanks, but If that conbination is not available, how can i enable this option? In VS2013. Additionaly, Can i use the same combination to apply it in xaml code?

Comment: Thanks, Snappawapa. In your link most of suggestions are wrong, Ctrl + F is for searchings, Ctrl + K is for bookmarks. The right one is Ctrl + K + D for whole doc and Ctrl + K + F for selection in VS2013. But first of all, I needed to reset the configurations.

Comment: @JezAvila No problem, glad to help. I posted this because it worked for me